# How to make an \item consisting of a list

Tags: lists, spacing

A list environment **[Edit: used to]** start a new paragraph. Thus, in

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{enumerate} \item Something \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

Nothing is printed at the right of the bullet, the number (1.) appears below. How can I get an enumerated list in an item, starting just after the bullet?

**I had this problem some time ago, before stackexchange existed; apologies for not checking the problem persisted.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please tell us what documentclass, packages and options you are using. When I compile

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Something
        \item Something else
    \end{enumerate}
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item even more
        \item and yet more
    \end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image: compiled example]

Comment: Indeed! One of many things I like about LaTeX is that unlike in majority of "wordprocessors", in LaTeX this sort of nesting actually works.

Comment: Sorry about the question. I did have this problem (repeatedly) some time ago and never got a solution. It is true that now works seamlesly.